# How to get two different hibernate session factories in camel

Tags: hibernate, apache-camel

I need to get data from two different databases in a route. For this, I need to have two different session factories. But my camel-context component can initialise only one hibernate session factory. Is there any way to resolve this ?

I am initialising sessions in spring and using camel's hibernate component.

Comment: We would need more information. How does your initialization code/config look like? Do you use Spring? Do you use Camel's JPA component?

Comment: @Wabi Yes using spring and camel's hibernate component.

Comment: You just create 2 hibernate components, and give them different names, and then use those different names in your Camel routes.